# Deleting an answer in the "low quality" moderator flag queue takes three deletes

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

In the moderator flag queue for Stack Overflow, if I delete an answer flagged as VLQ, it indicates that it's been deleted, while sending the call to the server.

However, the call fails the first two times, causing the answer to pop back open in the flag queue.

It's happened twice today, and only for answers (although I haven't tried to delete any questions).

Comment: Same here. When you go to the actual post and delete it from there (not from the queue), you get the *An error occurred…* popup.

Comment: @slhck As you can imagine, for *me*, this is a severe limitation.

Comment: Same here - after the _An error occurred_ popup the post is still there but has a single delete vote against it. It takes another go to properly delete

Comment: So this is how you've been inflating your stats.